# Self join to get maximum number of depth in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having an issue with multi level pages query using mysql.

My table structure is like this. The table name is 'default_pages'

```
id        title       parent_id
18        About Us    0
19        ab 1        18
20        contact     0
21        ab 2        18
22        sub 1       21
23        sub 2       22
```

My query is

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.title AS ptitle, parent.id AS parent, grandparent.id AS grandparent 
       FROM default_pages AS p 
       LEFT JOIN default_pages AS parent ON p.parent_id = parent.id 
       LEFT JOIN default_pages AS grandparent ON parent.parent_id = grandparent.id 
       where p.parent_id = 18
```

But I am getting the below output

```
id      ptitle      parent     grandparent
19      ab 1        18         null
21      ab 2        18         null
```

Desired output should be

```
id      ptitle      parent     grandparent
19      ab 1        18         null
21      ab 2        18         null
22      sub 1       21         18
23      sub 2       22         21
```

Comment: it would be easier to do by a recursive function, I don't think that it is possible to do with only one query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have direct support for hierarchical or recursive queries, so you have to approach this using a fixed number of multiple joins (or using a stored procedure).  I think you want to check for `18` in all the parent ids:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.title AS ptitle, parent.id AS parent, grandparent.id AS grandparent 
FROM default_pages p LEFT JOIN
     default_pages parent
     ON p.parent_id = parent.id LEFT JOIN
     default_pages grandparent
     ON parent.parent_id = grandparent.id 
WHERE 18 in (p.parent_id, parent.parent_id, grandparent.parent_id);
```

Comment: Awesome simply brilliant!!!... This is exactly what I wanted to do from yesterday. Thank you so so much. Now I have to understand the last where clause.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in your where clause, it limits the results to all rows where parent_id = 18. Instead, it seems you want all rows which have a parent. This should work:

```
SELECT p.id AS id, p.title AS ptitle, parent.id AS parent, grandparent.id AS grandparent 
       FROM default_pages AS p 
       LEFT JOIN default_pages AS parent ON p.parent_id = parent.id 
       LEFT JOIN default_pages AS grandparent ON parent.parent_id = grandparent.id 
       where p.parent_id != 0
```

Comment: Thanks Borre for going through the issue.Actually I accepted Gordon's solution as that is what I was looking for.Thanks once again.